# Get Contact Profile Data

Tags: xconnect, experience-profile

I'm trying to get a contact's profile data in Sitecore 9 u2. By profile data I mean data collected based on profile cards assigned to pages they visit. I'm using the `ContactBehaviorProfile` facet as one of my `ExpandOptions` while fetching the contact and using the method `Sitecore.XConnect.Contact.ContactBehaviorProfile` but the scores returned from that don't seem to match what I see in experience profile's profiling tab for the selected contact. [This documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-model/facets/calculated-facets/contact-behavior-profile.html) mentions it being the most recently matched profile data. Does that mean it doesn't get all of the contact's profile data? If it isn't then is there a different way to get all of a contact's profile data?